# Ограничить поиск места одним регионам в Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

Всем доброго дня. Вопрос такой. Подскажите пожалуйста, как в приложении с картами Гугл ограничить поиск одним регионом. Смысл таков , человек проживающий, например, в Казахстане открыв приложение с картой ,при наборе адреса в поле поиска, выподал список адресов только Казахстана.
Ни как не могу сделать.Куда копать, может ограничения ставить в настройках АПИ? Или прописывать в проекте? Да и смысл такой, что приложением будут пользоваться только из Казахстана. В других регионах это приложение будет показывать только Казахстан.